# "%" and "/" simbols difference in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to solve the FizzBuzz game.

I need to check if a number is divisible by 3. So, when we take a number and divide it by 3, we need that operation to have NO REST, or 0 REST.

The solution given to me is this:

```
def fizzbuzz(number)

  if number % 3 == 0
    return "Fizz"
  end
```

Why does they propose to use the "%"symbol? Why not the "/"symbol? Or both work as the same?

How should I check if the division has NO REST?

Comment: `%` and `/` do different things.

Comment: Can you point out specifically which parts of the documentation of the `/` and `%` you don't understand? That way, the documentation can be improved for future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**division operator** `/` - gives the quotient of the division whatever the remainder of the division is. So you cannot determine if a number is perfectly divisible (remainder = 0) or not perfectly divisible (with non-zero remainder) using a division operator (`/`).

```
10 / 3
#=> 3
```

**modulo operator** `%` - gives the remainder of the division. If perfectly divisible, the output is `0`, if not-perfectly divisible the output is non-zero value.

```
10 % 3
#=> 1
```

In your case `number % 3 == 0` is `true` only if `number` is divisible by 3 with 0 remainder (i.e if `number` passed into the method `frizzbuzz` is a multiple of 3 like -12, -3, 3, 6, 9, etc )

Answer (score 2):

Ruby has 4 division operators.

`divmod` returns the division and the remainder

```
  number = 15
  number.divmod(7) # => 2, 1
```

`modulo` alias `%` returns the remainder only

```
  number = 15
  number % 7 # => 1
  number.modulo(7) # => 1
```

`div` alias `/` returns the integer division if both operands are integers, and floating-point division if either operand is a float.

```
  number = 15
  number / 7 # => 2
  number.div(7) # => 2
  1.0 * number / 7 # => 2.142857142857143
```

`fdiv` always returns a full precision floating-point division

```
  number = 15
  number.fdiv(7) # => 2.142857142857143
```

Comment: `/` is general purpose division operator, not "integer division operator". It only does integer division on integers. But if either operand is a float, it returns fractional number.

Answer (score 0):

% is the Modulus - Divides left hand operand by right hand operand and returns remainder. \ is just the Divider. No Rest means that x % y == 0.

Answer (score 0):

lets take an example to understand better:

```
number1 = 12
number2 = 13
```

lets see if number1 and number2 is devisible by 4 ok?

```
number1 / 4 = 3 and the rest = 0
number2 / 4 = 3 and the rest = 1
```

so the "/" operation let us know the result of devision operation 
and the "%" operation let us know the rest of devision operation

so if we take our examples the number1 is devisible by 3 because

```
number1 % 3 = 0 ( the rest )
```